# Can I make Eclipse ignore the invalidity of the <g:plusone> tag in a jsp?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, google-plus-one

If you follow the directions [here](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) to add a +1 button to a jsp, Eclipse will show an error on that jsp.

Eclipse's JSP Editor says:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - taglib directive for "g" does not exist or TLD is not found.
>     - Unknown tag (g:plusone).

Amateras JSP Editor says:

> Unknown tag (g:plusone). taglib directive for "g" does not exist or TLD is not found.

This doesn't cause major problems in the project that I have noticed, but it does bring on some minor annoyances that come up often enough, like a warning dialog every time I commit using subclipse, as well as the red error x.

Is there a way to suppress or avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to the HTML5-valid version by using a div with class="g-plusone".

Example:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall"></div>
```